Derivative operator on $L_2([0, \, 1], \, \mathrm dx)$
Consider the dervative operator $A\psi = i\psi'$ on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H = L_2([0, \, 1], \, \mathrm dx)$, with domain
$$
D(A) = \left\{ \psi \in \mathcal H: \, \psi \text{ is absolutely continuous}, \, \psi' \in \mathcal H, \,\psi(0) = \psi(1) = 0 \right\}.
$$
We have
$$
D(A^\dagger) \supseteq \left\{ \psi \in \mathcal H: \, \psi \text{ is absolutely continuous}, \, \psi' \in \mathcal H \right\},
$$
where $A^\dagger$ is the adjoiont, since on this set we can integrate by parts and thus $A^\dagger\psi = i\psi'$ works fine. However, how can I be sure that equality holds?
Edit: i.e., how can I be sure that there are no functions $\varphi$ which are not absolutely continuous, such that there exists $\chi \in \mathcal H$ with $\langle \varphi | A\psi \rangle = \langle \chi | \psi \rangle$ for each $\psi \in D(A)$?
The example is taken from Thirring, Quantum Mathematical Physics, page 70, 2.5.3.3.

Hints: $-i\int \psi'\phi =\int \chi \psi$ for all $\psi \in D(A)$. Let $h(x)=\int_0^{x}\chi (t)dt$,  so that $-i\int \psi'\phi =\int h' \psi$. Integrating by parts we get $-i\int \psi'\phi =\int h \psi '$ or $\int \psi' [h+i\phi]=0$. Now let $g$ be any smooth function and define $\psi(x)=\int_0^{x}g(t)dt-x\int_0^{1}g(t)dt$. Then $\psi \in D(A)$. So we get $\int (g(x)-\int_0^{1}g(t)dt) [h+i\phi]=0$. Rewrite this as $\int g(h+i\phi)-\int_0^{1}g(t)dt (\int_0^{1}h(t)dt+i\int_0^{1}\phi (t)dt)=0$. Conclude that $h+i\phi=\int_0^{1}h(t)dt+i\int_0^{1}\phi (t)dt$. This makes $\phi$ absolutely continuous (since $h$ is absolutely continuous).
